# Link Command Failed with exit code (use -v to see invocation) [OpenCV on Obj C]

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opencv, bitcode

'm using the latest version of openCV (opencv 2.4.9) with xCode 7.1 beta 3
[And this the error message I got:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ6Wa.png)

Does anyone have an idea ? Thank You!
[thats what happens if I disabled bitcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSakw.png)